# How to configure the 500 error page in magento 2

Tags: magento2, php, error, redirect

Is there a way to set up a **custom 500 page error in magento 2**?

I tried to add a 500.phtml file in the **pub/errors/default** directory but this method only works with 404 errors and maintenance error 503.

I also tried to modify the .htaccess file by adding this line **ErrorDocument 500 500.html**, but invain.

For more information, I would like to customize this kind of 500 errors.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try add a **500.php** (with your custom code) in the **pub/errors** folder and add this line in the
**/pub** .htaccess file `ErrorDocument 500 /errors/500.php`

Hope this help.